# What is the most appropriate way to serve a large amount of parsed, static json data

Tags: json, database, heroku, flask

I have a large json file server-side that I'm parsing to make up a good deal of content across multiple pages of a website.  The json file will only be updated every month or two, although the structure will always stay the same.

As far as I can tell I have two solid options:

1. Parse the file, assembling the required data into various html templates that make up the raw text of the site itself
2. Parse the file into a database, and then make db/memcache calls on each page load

The database approach seems somewhat redundant though, as the data is basically static and so designing a database to hold it feels like overkill.  Having said that, parsing it into raw html to serve feels crude somehow.  Is there a more appropriate/sophisticated way to handle this data, or am I massively over-thinking the problem?

Comment: You could cache it in memory. As for static file vs. database, you'd have to run your own tests to see if it costs more resources to read the file and parse or fetch the data from a database.

Comment: It will definitely depend on the size of the JSON file (and whether it grows much). You can: read off-disk (easy, could be slow); cache into memory on startup (easy; fast; could eat RAM); cache into Redis or memcached (moderate; fast; limited by memory size of instance) or cache into a DB (moderate; moderately fast). If you can provide some more details about the JSON file it'll help give more direct advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large the JSON file is, it might be worth while to write a single script that ingests that data into a database (or sometype of memory cache). This would be especially advantageous, if you're generating content for different pages using subsets of the data in the JSON file rather than reading the entire JSON file. Redis or SQLite might be good candidates for this.

On the other hand, pre-parsing your JSON file into static HTML pages may not be so bad. In fact it may be faster since NGINX (or your webserver) doesn't have to proxy to flask. This is what NGINX does best. The webserver can be configured to expire cache in one or two months dending on your JSON update cycle.